# Static initialisers?

Tags: java, static

What is the difference between:

```
private static Object myVar = new Object();
```

And:

```
private static Object myVar2;

static{
    myVar2 = new Object();
}
```

In both case i end up with an initilized static variable

Comment: One is less verbose than the other one. Use the second one only if you can't use the first one.

Comment: precisely no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use better the second one if the initialisation of your static and maybe also final object is more complex.

E.g.:

```
static final MyClass something;

static {
    Config conf=SettingsManager.getSettings();
    MyClass obj=MyClassFactory.getInstance(conf);
    obj.setVodoo(true);
    something=obj;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In your example there is no difference and the compiled bytecode will end up exactly or very nearly the same. Static initializers are sometimes useful, but more often misused. If the goal is to populate a single static field, write a **static method** that returns the initialized object and call that method inside the static field declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the static initialiser block if creating your static object is more complicated. For example, it might require calling setters, or on a secondary intermediate object being set-up.

```
static {
  SomeConfig config = new SomeConfig();
  config.setMaxSize(10);
  config.setMinSize(1);
  YourObject object = new YourObject(config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are exactly same as evident by the content of class file:

```
  public class Test extends java.lang.Object{
  public Test();
    Code:
     0:   aload_0
     1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4:   return

 static {};
   Code:
    0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/Object
    3:   dup
    4:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    7:   putstatic       #3; //Field myVar2:Ljava/lang/Object;
    10:  return

}
```

You will get the same bytecode in either case. I generated bytecode by putting above options in Test.java file.